# What type of characters is this ù/î and how it's possible to convert into Chinese characters?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have this path: c:\Restore\20190213142118\Defaults侇侚\Defaults侇侚
This path is inserted in Oracle database. In oracle database this path it is display like this:`c:\Restore\20190213142118\Defaults î ù`

When I try to search by path in our database I don't find this row because I send this string: `c:\Restore\20190213142118\Defaults侇侚\Defaults侇侚` and doesn't find anything.

Can you give me the format of this string from database to convert in Visual Studio?

Comment: Get the collation of that Field and convert the Encoding? `SELECT * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY', 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_SORT')`. The `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is probably Windows 1252 or similar.

Comment: I think your question is putting you in the wrong direction. You should look at being able to insert the characters properly from the beginning. Looks like a problem with encoding.

Comment: @the_lotus  IIRC, in a previous question, the OP stated that the Database can not be modified, for some reason. Content included.